# ASP.NET MVC 4 Key-like characters in my URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC application.  When it comes up with its first page, the url looks like this:

`http://localhost:34293/(S(skrnsavxop5s4utkycfnzrvs))/MyController/MyAction`

What is the parenthetical between the port and the controller and where might it be coming from?  I'm really just looking for a place to get started, as I don't normally see this and don't have a clue where it is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using a "cookieless session state" mode.

Have a look at your `web.config`.

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)

[Cookieless Session State Explained](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Cookieless-Session-State.aspx)